# SSIS package config file windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have created SSIS package and make a deployment file and save credentional in dtConfig file.
Now I have to deploy ssis package on development machine. Need to change my username and password to windows based authentication of sql server. I have remove the username and password and set empty and change the server name but still getting connection issue.

I am using sql server 2008 r2

What I am missing here?

Comment: Exactly what errors are you getting and what are you doing when you get them? What username and password are you reffering to? Please update your question with this and any more detail you deem relevant.

Comment: Double click on the file and press execute button it gives me the error. The acquire connection method call to connection manager failed.